# Can we have more time ranges in next year's survey?

Tags: feature-request, survey-2017

The 2017 Developer Survey had two questions (How long since you first learned to code? How long have you been coding professionally?) for which the answers topped out at 20+ years. Since a lot of us started coding at 12, and the median age from last year's survey was 27, I'm predicting that about 40% of the respondents will choose 20+ for the first question, and about 25% will choose 20+ for the second.

If it's important to know the difference between 17 years and 18, that's fine, but I propose that we also split "20+" into:

- 20-24 years
- 25-29 years
- 30-39 years
- 40-49 years
- 50-59 years
- 60-69 years
- 70+ years (I **am** Grace Hopper!)

Comment: Or they could just make it a slider like a couple of the other questions.

Comment: Perhaps the point is that after 20+ years, it doesn't really matter. You've been doing it long enough to get all the acclaim possible. Do we really need more granularity here?

Comment: Depends on the point of the question. Why have 20 buckets below 20, and then lump the other 25-40% into a single bucket?

Comment: upvoted because I want to be able to _eventually_ state that I started coding 70 years ago. Another option needed is "I forgot"

Comment: @gnat: Same thing, right? ;)

Comment: Because of this, I felt old for the first time in my life while answering this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so many when you could do it yourself?

There are two ways to remove all the options and replace it with something where the survey taker manually inputs the year ranges. One is like what @NathanOlvier suggested, which is just a slider:

> Or they could just make it a slider like a couple of the other questions.

Or you could make a text box where the user inputs a number. But due to extra checking for an *actual* number inputted, I believe the slider option would be optimal and would prevent troll answers (i.e. 1000 years of experience).

Comment: Troll answers could easily be disregarded by not allowing the user to enter a value higher than, say 60, and lower than perhaps 1.

Comment: You do not need any additional extra checks by using HTML's `type="number"`. It also natively supports `min`, `max` and `step`. Browsers will automatically report an invalid number. So there are no technical difficulties here at all. (The same goes with `type="range"` -- it acts exactly as `type="number"`, so it's just a different visual representation of the same thing.)

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for this suggestion.  On last year's survey we "topped out" at 11 or more years; this year we essentially doubled the range.  We'll be looking at the data to see if there are "buckets" in the high range that make sense from an analysis perspective.

Comment: Consider that capturing the actual number lets you re-bin the data at a future date when you dream up a new analysis angle.